# Convert Int to Float Without return String Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I want to convert an int value to a float without returning a string value. If I use `parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)` it returns a string value. Example "15000.00". I want to return without a string of 15000.00.

Is there any solution?

My expect returns value which is not a string, I need like -> 15000.00
not "15000.00"

The other API requires me to return value to float form. Postman displays {{Key 'estimation_cost' error: 150000 should be instance of 'float'","hint":"Check the request body"}"

Code:

```
var cost_float = parseFloat(result_2.purchase_request_line[i].estimation_cost).toFixed(2)
result_2.purchase_request_line[i].estimation_cost = cost_float
```

> message": "404 - {"status":"error","msg":" / Key 'estimation_cost' error: 150000 should be instance of 'float'","hint":"Check the request body"}",

My Return "estimation_cost": "150000.00",

Comment: Numbers don't care about trailing decimal `0` digits. `15000` is the same number as `15000.0`, and `15000.00`, and `15000.0000000`. The difference can only be represented in a string.

Comment: The technical explanation of Amadan's comment is that in JavaScript, all numbers (with the exception of BigInts) are actually 64 bit floating point. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: If you just want to have a fixed number of decimal places, you can parse the string back to a number, or use math to round the originally parsed number.

Comment: the other API requires me to return value to float form. Postman displays "Key 'estimation_cost' error: 150000 should be an instance of 'float'"

Comment: Could include that info in your question, in detail?

Comment: i believe there is no solution to your demand. javascript is a high level language, so it manages datatype for you. that's why `int`, `float`, etc, got reduced to just `number` datatype and `number` does not keep `.00` because it knows that's useless.

Comment: If you want to represent a currency value, I suggest you to use `cent` as the minimal unit. So it could be `1500000 cent`. But when you need to display it, time it by `0.01` to become dollars. That's how currency is handled for most of the database, not a float value.

Comment: 1. Where is your code running? 2. What are the APIs involved? 3. What are you using Postman for?

Comment: How does API look like? What code do you use to submit? Do you use JSON as POST body? JSON does not distinguish ints and floats, and `15000` (but not `"15000"` or `"15000.00"`) should be accepted as a `float` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an `int` in Javascript. All numbers are IEEE 754 floats already.

If you are trying to round to 2 decimal places, you can do `Math.round(x*100)/100`.

Comment: the other api requires me to return value to float form. Postman displays "Key 'estimation_cost' error: 150000 should be instance of 'float'"

Comment: If you're using Postman, everything is a string anyway.

Comment: @Adim that must be an error coming from the server that provides the API. You should show us the documentation of that API so we can see what it is expecting.

Comment: @Adim also, what happens if you just hardcode the number `15000` and send that to the API? Does it work? If so, just use the rounding method from my answer if you need to round to 2 d.p.

Comment: @AndrewParks same error sir

Comment: @Adim it's possible that the remote server is providing incorrect error messages, and there is something else wrong with your request. Until you can make the API work directly with Postman using hard-coded values, you are going to be randomly guessing at how to make the Javascript provide the correct values for the API

Comment: @AndrewParks thanks sir, i will crosscheck the other api with remote server